# Java EE 5, how to run external process on Singleton Bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, process, singleton, weblogic

I must start an long running external process from Java EE 5 application, and abstract this process to other beans as stateful managed bean. Lifetime of the process must be tied to lifetime of Java EE application.

Simply, the bean starts the process during it's initialization via `Runtime` API, and provides interface to interact with the process, internally writing and reading on the IO channel. The process is open all the time.

It must be ensured the container instantiates only single instance, and always inject this specific instance. The instance must exist as long as the application is running. The instance should be initialized during deployment, and disposed during undeployment or server shutdown. Thus, lifecycle hooks must be available to open and close the process during these phases.

It doesn't matter if this bean is bundled in EAR, or deployed as distinct library module, as long as it's available in the application and meets the requirements.

I know about annotations like `@Singleton` and `@ApplicationScoped`, but these are Java EE 6 annotations. How is this possible in Java EE 5?

Comment: Let me think .... what if process is "physically" started in independent way (example: windows service) and "logically" controlled via this bean?

Comment: The application must have control over the process and lifetime must be tied to application

Comment: Also, the JNI is not an option here, as the stability of the JVM must be guaranteed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that your best bet is to tie onto the [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

The code would be something like:

```
package tld.yourcompany.your.java.package;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class ProcessManagerContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // shut down the process
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // start up your process
    }
}
```

And then, because you're in a prehistoric environment, you'll need to modify the web.xml to have:

```
<web-app ...>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
             tld.yourcompany.your.java.package.ProcessManagerContextListener 
        </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

The ServletContextListener was part of EE 1.3 so you should be fine to use it.

Comment: Good to hear I ended up in same conclusion

Answer (score 1):

To simulate a singleton without `@Singleton`, you only need to ensure you have exactly *one* stateful bean. [With Weblogic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/EJBTuning.html#1135433):

```
<weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <ejb-name>YourEJB</ejb-name>
    <entity-descriptor>
        <entity-cache>
            <max-beans-in-cache>1</max-beans-in-cache>
        </entity-cache>
    </entity-descriptor>
</weblogic-enterprise-bean>
```